# Поиск элемента в двумерном массиве

Tags: java, строки

Помогите чайнику с адресной книгой. Имеется объект

```
public class Contact {   
    public String name;
    public String email;
    public String phone;
    public String address;
}
```

И имеется массив `book[26]`, который состоит из `ArrayLists` сортирован по англ. алфавиту. Надо удалить контакт `void remove(String name)`. Как правильно написать код поиска `name` в двумерном массиве?

```
public void remove(String name)
{
    char a = name.charAt(0);
    char b = 'a';
    int n = b-'0';
    for(int i=0;i<book[n].size();i++)
    {
        if(((Contact) book[n].get(i)).getName().equals(name))
            book[n].remove(i);              
    }
}
```

Могу ли я воспользоваться методом `contains()`? Если да, то подскажите как? Не очень понятно как метод работает.

Comment: @ALonaG, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @ALonaG, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю, у вас массив из ArrayList'ов, которые в свою очередь тоже являются массивами из объектов класса Contact? Проверить надо поле name объекта класса Contact? Если все верно, то почему бы не пройтись в цикле по каждому элементу массива `ArrayList<Contact>`, который является элементом массива `ArrayList`, и удалять.
Почитайте про двумерные массивы и тогда будет яснее картина. Удачи!